# Data Type Mismatch: Type is -4 with MySQL 5.1.47 and CachedRowSetImpl

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using Java with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.47 connecting to a 5.0.96 MySQL database (I've tried with other databases).

Here is a MWE :

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws SQLException {
    MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://database:3306/dbname");

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

        CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
         connection.prepareStatement("SELECT BLOB_FIELD FROM MY_TABLE")) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                cachedRowSet.populate(resultSet);
            }

            while (cachedRowSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(cachedRowSet.getBlob(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error output is:

```
Type is : -4
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Datatype mismatch
    at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.getBlob(CachedRowSetImpl.java:5794)
    at Scratch.main(scratch_63.java:29)
```

If I remove the CachedRowSetImpl, I don't get this error. But in production, where we also use the CachedRowSet and MySQL databases, we don't get this error. After investigatin the error is thrown by this block :

```
public Blob getBlob(int var1) throws SQLException {
    this.checkIndex(var1);
    this.checkCursor();
    if (this.RowSetMD.getColumnType(var1) != 2004) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(this.resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.type").toString(), this.RowSetMD.getColumnType(var1)));
        throw new SQLException(this.resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.dtypemismt").toString());
    } else {
        this.setLastValueNull(false);
        Blob var2 = (Blob)((Blob)this.getCurrentRow().getColumnObject(var1));
        if (var2 == null) {
            this.setLastValueNull(true);
            return null;
        } else {
            return var2;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to happen because MySQL translates the BLOB (2004) data type to the LONGVARBINARY datatype (-4)

What are different ways we can mitigate this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried using `getBytes` instead of `getBlob` in `Scratch.main`?

Comment: I am working a fairly large legacy codebase and I can't rewrite those parts, as I am looking the reproduce the exact test environnement